# Wrong date conversion

Tags: java, android, date

I have a problem in date conversion in my android application.
I have date strings like `2017-11-11 11:52` which its date is equal to `2017-Nov-11` but it is parsed as `2017-01-11` in below code snippet:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm");
try {
    Date date = df.parse("2017-11-11 11:52");
    Log.v("DATE_TAG","Date Time:"+date.toString());

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The log output of above code is "Wed Jan 11 11:52:00 GMT+03:30 2017".

Is there anything wrong in my date format string?

Comment: You need to get this format 2017-Nov-11 rgt?

Comment: The above SimpleDateFormat format makes no sense to me. Why do you want to format `"2017-11-11 11:52"` as `"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm"`, if it's already in that format?

Comment: Refer to [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly noted from your output : [Read Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> D is Day in year (1-365)
>   d is day in month (1-31)

Change this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

to

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong dateformat.
*DD* stands for the day of the year, not the day of the month. You have to use *dd* instead.
You can check the [SimpleDateFormat documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), where it is stated that *DD* can range from 1 to 365.

So your code should look like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
try {
  Date date = df.parse("2017-11-11 11:52");
  Log.v("DATE_TAG","Date Time:"+date.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can i ask why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: Good question, @W3hri. This one is the best explained of the three correct answers.

Comment: The one from Gowtham was downvoted too, a bit suspicious ...

Comment: But neither is anymore. Someone changed their mind in time.

Comment: You're right. Strange

Comment: @W3hri Yeah all three answers were right. Someone is playing with this votes!

Comment: Nice catch @W3hri!!

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam I have up-voted all 3 answers but I don't know why somebody down-voted these answers!

Answer (score 2):

`D` is day in year  e.g  189. Use `d` instead

Answer (score 0):

`D` is used for (Day in year), so in you case you need to use `d` (is day in month ). please use this Format   `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`